# fast way to find the characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.
$ \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
 7/34 & -11/34 & 4/17 & -1/17 \\
-11/34  & 27/34  & 1/17  & 4/17 \\
4/17  & 1/17  & 31/34  & 5/34  \\
 -1/17  & 4/17  & 5/34  & 3/34 \end{array} \right)$

Calculate the characteristic polynomial of this matrix is very long (there are no zeroes) so I  would like to know which is the fastest way to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix.

The computer says the the characteristic polynomial is

$$ t^2 (t-1)^2 $$

Comment: To make your calculations nicer you could multiply all entries by 34. This would have the effect of multiplying the eigenvalues by 34 too.

Answer (score 0):

It's a hard to answer what is the *fastest* way, but if you see the definition of characteristic polynomial $\det(A-\lambda I)$, where $A$ is your given matrix, $I$ the identitity matrix, and $\lambda$ is the eigenvalues, what you called $t$.
Then after [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Examples) and simplification its easy to see, that the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4-2\lambda^3+\lambda^2$, what you can write into the form $\lambda^2(\lambda-1)^2$. After that the eigenvalues are $1, 1, 0, 0$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the Laplace expansion and simplification?